# Same C program but different execution time

Tags: c

I wrote a C program to find out the prime numbers in a given parameter. But for the same input and output, the program has different execution times.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int n,p,k;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int prime[n+1];
    for (p = 2; p <= n; ++p)
    {
        if (prime[p]!=-1)
        {
            for (int i = p*2,k=2; i < n; k++,i=k*p)
            {
                prime[i]=-1;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < n ; ++i)
    {
        if (prime[i]!=-1)
        {
            printf("%d  ",i );
        }
    }
return 0;
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: The execution of your program on your PC is not dependent only on the code but on some other environment variables such as CPU load which probably causes the delay in the second execution.

Comment: Check the overall state of your machine. Is it same in two executions?

Comment: Show the code. -----------

Comment: Are you testing on a laptop? Could it have throttled the CPU on battery power? Need more details.

Comment: Newbie in programming and also don't know much about the ways computers works. but had same number of tasks going on while executing. I also executed them one right after another.

Comment: [Edit] your question to add the code. Don't bury it in the comments where it is difficult to read and easy to miss. Also, don't post images of text. Just copy and paste the text output directly into the question.

Comment: instead of `scanf("%d", &n);` do `n=200`. then run it twice. Also remove printf as its execution time might varry significally

Comment: You are measuring wall-clock time. During that time your computer did (or did not do) many things other than running your program: it downloaded a virus from the internet, it repainted your windows, it move a few disk blocks around for performance, ... You should measure **process time** instead.

Comment: Maybe you did not enter 200 quick enough in the slower attempt. (see P_J_'s comment above). Besides all the technical things already mentioned (CPU throttling, total workload etc.) the human factor is a very plausible reason for what you see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The execution of a program on an environment is not dependent only on the code but on some other environment variables such as CPU load.

CLOCKS_PER_SEC is a constant which is declared in <time.h>. To get the CPU time used by a task within a C application, use:

```
clock_t begin = clock();

/* Do the work. */

clock_t end = clock();
double time_spent = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
```

For your program, You can probably check the

1. CPU Time took on input.
2. CPU Time is taken to generate Prime Number
3. ...... and so on

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<time.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int n,p,k;
    clock_t t , t1, t2; 
    t = clock(); 
    scanf("%d", &n);
    t = clock() - t; 
    double time_taken = ((double)t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC; // in seconds 
    printf("Took %f seconds to take the input\n", time_taken); 
    
    
    
    t2 = clock(); 
    int prime[n+1];
    for (p = 2; p <= n; ++p)
    {
        if (prime[p]!=-1)
        {
            for (int i = p*2,k=2; i < n; k++,i=k*p)
            {
                prime[i]=-1;
            }
        }
    }
    t2 = clock() - t2;
    double time_taken2 = ((double)t2)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC; // in seconds 
    printf("Took %f seconds for generating the prime number \n", time_taken2); 
    
  
    for (int i = 1; i < n ; ++i)
    {
        if (prime[i]!=-1)
        {
            printf("%d  ",i );
        }
    }
return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
200                                                                                                                     
Took 0.000075 seconds to take the input                                                                                 
Took 0.000004 seconds for generating the prime number                                                                   
1  2  3  5  7  11  13  17  19  23  29  31  37  41  43  47  53  59  61  67  71  73  79  83  89  97  101  103  107  109  1
13  127  131  137  139  149  151  157  163  167  173  179  181  191  193  197  199
```

The time is depended on your CPU load. For details please visit [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-measure-time-taken-by-a-program-in-c/)

Answer (score 4):

What you are measuring is the time it takes the user to type the input, i.e. 200.

Calculating the result after the input is given will not take 2 to 5 sec on any modern computer.

It is true that "the computer may be doing other things" and therefore give varying execution time - but that won't give you a 3 sec increase in code like this.

To make the measurement more reliable, you need to "remove" the user input, i.e. remove the `scanf`.

Instead of `scanf` you should give the value of `n` as a command line argument.

Use code like

```
// scanf("%d", &n); Dont use scanf but use lines like the two below.
if (argc < 2) exit(1); // user error - no number given
n = atoi(argv[1]);     // convert command line arg to integer
```

And start the program like:

```
test2.exe 200
```

Now the measured time will be much smaller than 2-5 sec and you won't see execution time vary so much.

Note: While `atoi` is simple to use, it's in general better to use `strtol`